# Woocommerce PHP Webhook Not working

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks

I'm using this code in my functions.php file of the Storefront child theme in Wordpress.

```
<?php
function action_woocommerce_api_create_order( $order_id, $data, $instance ) { 
    include get_stylesheet_directory().'/agilephpcode/CurlLib/curlwrap_v2.php';
    $event_json = array(
      "start"=>1455256687,
      "end"=>1455246687,
      "title"=>"this is a test event",
      "contacts"=>array(5631986051842048),
      "allDay"=>false
    );

    $event_json = json_encode($event_json);
    curl_wrap("events", $event_json, "POST", "application/json");
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_api_create_order', 'action_woocommerce_api_create_order');
```

?>

I've tested the code from the Include to the end of the curl_wrap on an individual php page and it creates an event in Agile CMS. The event would be like a party or a meeting, not a coding event :)

Anyway, it doesn't create the event and I've tried for about four hours to get it to work. Is there something big that I'm missing here? I simply want to make the call. I realize making a party event or something from the creation of an order (after they've paid) isn't logical.

Comment: Ooops, put the include within the function. now it's above the function call, but still doesn't work.

Comment: I just had to change the action to 'woocommerce_new_order' and it seems to work just fine now. Here's the code:

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include get_stylesheet_directory().'/agilephpcode/CurlLib/curlwrap_v2.php';
function action_woocommerce_api_create_order( $order_id, $data, $instance ) { 
    $event_json = array(
      "start"=>1455256687,
      "end"=>1455246687,
      "title"=>"this is a test event4",
      "contacts"=>array(5631986051842048),
      "allDay"=>false
    );

    $event_json = json_encode($event_json);
    curl_wrap("events", $event_json, "POST", "application/json");
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'action_woocommerce_api_create_order');
```

?>